# Почему не грузятся Яндекс карты на Android, библиотека MapKit 3.0?

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Использую бесплатную версию библиотеки MapKit (3.0) для Android, в процессе подключения библиотеки возникла проблема отображения самой карты

После успешного подключения библиотеки с ключем:

```
MapKitFactory.setApiKey("Ключ полученный через личный кабинет разработчика яндекса");
```

В процессе запуска приложения карты не загружаются

[image: Отображение карты]

Листинг кода:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.yandex.mapkit.Animation;
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory;
import com.yandex.mapkit.geometry.Point;
import com.yandex.mapkit.map.CameraPosition;
import com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapKitFactory.setApiKey("Здесь мой ключ из кабинета разработчика яндекс");
        MapKitFactory.initialize(this);

        // Укажите имя activity вместо map.
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.getMap().move(
                new CameraPosition(new Point(55.751574, 37.573856), 11.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0),
                null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mapView.onStop();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }
}
```

В лог при этом пишется следующее сообщение :

> `E/zygote: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe E/yandex.maps:`
>   `yandex::maps::runtime::network::common::DnsCache::resetLocalResolver:`
>   `Invalid argumentfailed to parce address from web.adfox.ru.`
>   `E/yandex.maps:`
>   `yandex::maps::runtime::network::common::DnsCache::resetLocalResolver:`
>   `Invalid argumentfailed to parce address from web.adfox.ru.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратился в тех поддержку яндекса, прислали письмо с текстом, что активировали мой ApiKey на стороне сервера, проблема ушла.

Answer (score 1):

После получения ключа может пройти какое-то время, прежде чем он активируется и карты начнут отображаться. В моем случае все заработало примерно через час